# microsoft excel - vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and was trying to write code to search 5 names(in sheet2), in sheet1 having few names, using `For Loop`.

But while run this, code gives error,

> object variable or with block variable not set

How do I get rid from it?

```
Sub find()
    Sheets("sheet2").Activate
    For x = 1 To 5
        Cells(x, 1).Select
        var1 = Selection.Copy
        Sheets("sheet1").Activate
        Dim search As Range
        Set search = range("a1:f9").find(var1).Activate
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to dim var1 as a type, have a look at VBA variable declaration.

Comment: `Selection.Copy` returns boolean. So `var1` type become boolean. 1st argument of `Find` method must be any type of string (string, variant/string or object/string), not boolean. This causes the error. Use `var1 = CStr(Selection.Value)`

Comment: It's cleaner to declare your variables at the top of the sub or in General Declaration if they're global.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use this modified VBA code, help you to match & return names between two Sheets.*

**Before RUN Macro:**

[image]

```
   Sub QuickSearch()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Sheets(2)
    Set rng1 = ws2.Range(ws2.[a2], ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    With rng1.Offset(0, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet10!C[-1]:C,1,FALSE),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

- You may enter this code with any of the Sheets as Standard Module.

**After RUN Macro:**

[image]

**N.B.**

```
ws2.Range(ws2.[a2], ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
```

- *In this code line `[a2]` (cell reference) & `"A"` (Column Name), are editable.*

Answer (score 0):

`Selection.Copy` is an *object*, so the command

```
var1 = Selection.Copy
```

produces your error - it have to be

```
Set var1 = Selection.Copy
```

But it is not what you wanted — you wanted *the content (text) of the selection in your variable `var1`*.

So use

```
var1 = Selection.Text
```

instead.

Comment: thank you for your comment i have changed it to var1= selection.text but now it is giving runtime error 424 object required.